# Why are my unit tests failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Howdy, I'm having a bit of a problem getting my unit tests to pass.  Specifically, the ones in ***cart_test.rb*** are failing.

```
  test "add two different items" do
    cart = Cart.create
    book_one = products(:one)
    book_two = products(:two)
    cart.add_product(book_one.id).save!
    cart.add_product(book_two.id).save!
    assert_equal 2, cart.line_items.size
    assert_equal book_one.price + book_two.price, cart.total_price
  end

  test "add two unique items" do
    cart = Cart.create
    ruby_book = products(:ruby)
    cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!
    cart.add_product(ruby_book.id).save!
    assert_equal 2*ruby_book.price, cart.total_price
    assert_equal 1, cart.line_items.size
    assert_equal 2, cart.line_items[0].quantity
  end
```

Here's my repository: https://github.com/zackster/Agile-Web-Development-w--Rails----DEPOT-application

Could somebody please help me understand what's going on? I *believe* the tests are failing because the items aren't actually being added to the cart, but it could be something else entirely [I'm a rails novice  ]. . . thanks!

Comment: It seems like the unit tests are doing what they are supposed to do, and the program itself has the problems.

Comment: I agree.. so why does the program have problems?

Comment: That's an awfully big question. What the error look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CartTest tests are failing because in Cart::add_product, you aren't actually tying a new line_item to a cart -- just creating orphaned line_items with a raw `LineItem.create`. To tie to a cart, you can change the line that was creating a LineItem with no relationship to the cart:

```
current_item = LineItem.new(:product_id => product_id, :price => product_price)
```

to actually create a new line item in the current cart's line_items collection:

```
current_item = line_items.create(:product_id => product_id, :price => product_price)
```

There were some other failures that you didn't specifically ask about, but I looked into them anyways...

Your products.yml does not specify an id field, so the product_id of 1 in line_items.yml does not end up referencing any product when you run the fixtures. You can hard-code `id: 1`, etc in your products.yml to address this.

Next, there is just a typo in the CartsControllerTest -- `@cart_id` isn't defined, and should instead be `@cart.id`

Finally, that unveils one other problem, which is actually a logic problem. Now your test to destroy a product fails, but this is actually because your logic does not allow you to destroy a product that has line_items (which your product does once we fixed the products.yml file to have ids specified). So... really the test is wrong and the code is right there, I suppose.

Comment: By the way, to expound on that line_items.create construct, your Product is defined with `has_many` line_items. So, because of that, you can reference line_items in the context of a product. Rails gives you a bunch of auto-generated methods on has_many items. More can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html  and this is an example of using `others.create(...)`

Comment: Where is the test to destroy a product failing? BTW, now that I'm looking at product.rb (line 21), I have "if line_items.count.zero?".  Should it instead be, "if self.line_items.count.zero?"  ? Thanks again for a super helpful answer!

Comment: `line_items.count.zero?` is fine, but the problem is, you *do* actually have some line items corresponding to your product (now that the fixtures are referencing them), so your own code won't let you delete it. So you would probably want to modify your test to be sure that the deletion fails in that case instead of expecting it to succeed. And then you could add another test that tries to delete a product that has no line items, which should succeed. Glad it was helpful :)